# Is there a way to check that which manifest imported some uses-permission?

Tags: android

I removed some sensitive permissions, such as SMS related permission, phone call permissions, and so on, from my app AndroidManifest file. However, I found in the generated full merged AndroidManifest file in the build folder, there still exits such permission. I think this is because some 3rd library using it. The question is, is there some convenient way to find out which component/aar imported such permission? There are too many such modules.

Comment: delete your build folder and re build project.

Comment: @LearningAlways you can use clean build simply. But that is not the issue I suppose.

Comment: did you try?? delete build folder and re build??

Comment: @mianlaoshu Open AndroidManifest.xml, at the bottom you will see two tabs. Text|Merged Manifest. Click on Merged Manifest and you will get access to all the individual manifest files on the right pane.

Comment: @MohammedAtif great! thanks~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it as follows:

1. Open the Manifest.xml from your app
2. Click on `Merged Manifest` tab at the bottom
3. Select the permission

[image: merged]
In the Merging log at the bottom, you will see which module added this permission